# How do I fix the Space Center Great Work bug?

Tags: simcity-2013

I have fully developed cities in the region with excess workers. I created also residential only city but I have this problem in phase 2 . that Space center halted , No worker 0/300 .

Does anyone have work around this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

According to many sources online, this is called the Space Center Great Work bug.  A fix does exist, but requires the use of two mods.

From [simcityplanningguide.com](http://www.simcityplanningguide.com/2014/09/SimCitySpacePortGreatWorkFix.html):

> The reason that the workers never arrive to the great work construction
>   site is that the road from the space center to the regional freeway
>   does not connect properly. In order to get the intersection properly
>   connected, you can use Skye's Regional Freeway Mod to create a 4th leg
>   to the intersection. There's only a small amount of space to do this
>   because the railroad is in the way, but you can place a short dead-end
>   segment between the intersection and the tracks. (Editor's note: Not
>   every map has a railroad across the street. Just build a 4th leg. It
>   doesn't matter how long it is. Regional freeways can cross regional
>   railways too, so you can build past the railroad tracks if you like.)
>
> [image]
>
> Once you place the 4th leg to the intersection, the 300 workers
>   necessary to build will start arriving. If it doesn't register the
>   workers arriving right away, and you're a little impatient, you can
>   close and restart your game. In the video demonstration below, I
>   exited to the main menu and jumped back to the city three times before
>   it worked. If you're not impatient, you can just let it sit and it
>   should eventually build. Both methods work.
>
> The best part about this fix is that it works in both online and
>   offline games. Special thanks goes to Mark Norris from the SimNation
>   Guild who brought this to my attention, tested it out on multiple maps
>   and found that it worked every time. He also found that you can delete
>   the segment after your workers are done building the great work. You
>   can read Mark's comments on the fix below the video.

- Skye's mod can be downloaded from here: [LINK](http://skyestorme.com/skyes-regional-freeway-mod/)
- CammodB1 can be downloaded from here: [LINK](http://skyestorme.com/cammodb1-by-danny-mod/)